# Check if twitter account has been deactivated?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I'm using the twitter4j API and I want to see if, given the ID of a user's account, if that account has been deactivated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`users/show`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show).  It will give you an error code if the user has been suspended.

For example

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=nero`

Returns

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 63,
      "message": "User has been suspended."
    }
  ]
}
```

If you only have the ID, you can make a similar call - `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=.....`

With Twitter4J you use [`showUser`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#showUser-long-) and pass it either the string of the username, or the int of the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no dedicated method to do this but using [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) (in your case [this](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/2.2.6/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html#lookupUsers(long[])) method) with the user ids you are getting back the the active users only. **So if some id is missing from the response those users are the suspended ones**.